# Field boosting in elasticsearch with django-haystack

Tags: python, django, boost, elasticsearch, django-haystack

We're trying to implement field boosting in Elasticsearch using Django Haystack 2.1.0 and pyelasticsearch 0.6. If I `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_mapping?pretty=true`, I get a response (extraneous parts removed) of

```
{
  "haystack" : {
    "modelresult" : {
      "_boost" : {
        "name" : "boost",
        "null_value" : 1.0
      },
      "properties" : {
        "headline" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "boost" : 1.5,
          "analyzer" : "snowball",
          "store" : "yes",
          "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets"
        },
        }
    }
}
```

So far we're only trying to boost the "headline" field. Even using a boost of something absurd like 5000 shows no effect on the output. Is there something we're missing?

Comment: Struggling with the exact same issue... did you found any solution so far ?

Comment: Could you show your `search_indexes.py` file ? To see how're you configuring the boost in Haystack ?